Is it possible to access and store biometric data from IOS and Android devices into my own database for analysis?
I am doing a project for my school FYP. So my topic is to develop an mobile app to collect users' biometric data for vulnerability assessment/analysis. And suggest mitigation strategy to mitigate vulnerabilities and potential side-channel attacks.
I am using react-native as my front-end, and now i am about to do my back-end(probably Flask).
And I have done a few research and it seems that iOS and Android don't allow access to raw biometric data or even encrypted biometric data from users for storing in a database due to privacy and security concerns. So my question is is it possible to collect biometric data from phone and store it into my own database? If yes, what should i use? Thanks.

It is not possible on iOS. iOS doesn't even have access to biometric data. Biometric data is collected directly by the Secure Enclave. On request, the secure enclave will perform a biometric verification and return the result to iOS.
